# Question about supremum of series

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

By the monotone convergence theorem for sequences, we know that: $$ \sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n = \sup_{N\in\mathbb N}\left \{\sum_{n= 1}^N a_n\right\}$$
My question then, is whether this supremum is also equal to: $$ \sup_{i_1,\dots ,i_k \    \in \ \mathbb N}\left \{a_{i_1} + \dotsb +a_{i_k}\right\}$$
A proof I've worked out in my head says yes, but when writing it I get lost a bit in the details. Is this true then? Thank you.

Edit: The question is for a series of non-negative terms, which allows us to use the monotone convergence theorem. Also, either suppose the series converges or allow the supremum to take infinite value.

Comment: Assuming all $a_n \geqslant 0$, yes. Any finite sum is not larger than the sum of all $a_n$, and the second $\sup$ is never smaller than the first.

Comment: @DanielFischer Yes, I forgot the detail of non-negativity.